# How does the QR code login work in Discord and how can I recreate it?

Tags: authentication, jwt

If I want to log in to the Discord webapp/desktop app, I can do it via a QR code. This is scanned with the Discord mobile app and you are immediately logged into the web app/desktop app. Pretty handy and goes pretty fast. I took a closer look at the QR code. For example, the URL behind it is this one:

```
https://discord.com/ra/GmI8x8mpsHTCAzVCTWP4tBLFwDmwJOUtMJr4cestr_Q
```

I have two questions about this:

1. how exactly does this registration via QR code work.
2. how can I recreate this using JWT?

Background: At the moment i have two apps, one webapp developed with svelte and one mobile app for iOS and Android developed with React Native. For my backend system i am using mongodb realm. So i just need to create the login flow itself and give mongodb a unique created userID. A user is created and a session is initiated.

Answer (score 2):

I've wondered about this too. I've noticed that there's a 'Debug' tab on the Discord mobile app, which holds all the requests. I tried to login by a QR Code, looked at the Debug tab, and saw this:

```
POST https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/remote-auth
POST https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/remote-auth/cancel
POST https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/remote-auth/finish
```

I think you need to add an `Authorization` header with a token to the request, but I'm not quite sure. I'll try to update this later if I remember.

EDIT: So, I've found [this](https://github.com/Vap0r1ze/discord-remote-auth/blob/master/src/types/RemoteAuthClient.js#L26), along with many other results when I googled Discord Remote-Auth. Most of the examples use websockets, so I'll keep searching

EDIT 2: I found [this!](https://luna.gitlab.io/discord-unofficial-docs/mobile_remote_auth.html)